# Which version of JDK, SDK and NDK Unity 2019.2.21f1 require?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have downloaded Unity manually from here:[Unity download archive](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive)

But within the torrent, it does not provide an option for JDK, SDK, and NDK download.

[image]

Now, which are the right version of these tools to download?

I have already used Unity HUB but this version of Unity is not compatible with the Unity HUB because I want to download the latest Unity version for my project.

Unity HUB does not provide support for any other version of the Unity.

Answer (score 2):

- Android SDK - [**The Latest Version**]
- OpenJDK - [**The Latest Version**]
- Android NDK - [**r16b**]